# Playing .mov .mp4 in diffent resolution size in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have to develop a player in iPhone that play videos. I have not much background in video encoding and signal encoding. When I test some .mp4 and .mov file I see that only the video with resolution that fits the iPhone screen size can be played and larger size cannot be played. Are there any solutions to play all the movie size on iPhone in that case. Please give me some instruction. Many thanks in advance. The code to play the video is below:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.65.123.108/test1.mov"];

//this movie has size of 480x272 can be played, other larger resolution cannot be played


_moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                 initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_moviePlayer];

_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this, unless you can scale the video down before you play it. It would probably be inefficient though.

Comment: You meaned the size of video must fit the screen size, and no way to play all resolution in iPhone?

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't have much experience with movies on iPhone, but from what I heard, you can play HD movies on the iPad, whereas you can't on an iPhone or iPod touch.